# localForage type is unkown

Tags: typescript, localforage

```
const AddMovieToDashboardFn = (movie) => {
  localForage.getItem('my array').then((value) => {
    const x: string[] = value;
    console.log(x)
  });
}
```

const x has a syntax error:

> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.

The value parameter in the `then` callback is of type `unknown` so the error makes sense. If I like the `value` it shows an array. How do I give the `value` in the then callback a type, should be type array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const AddMovieToDashboardFn = (movie) => {
  localForage.getItem('my array').then((value: string[]) => {
    const x = value;
    console.log(x)
  });
}
```

Or, since the typing for localforage allows passing a type parameter (https://github.com/localForage/localForage/blob/master/typings/localforage.d.ts):

```js
const AddMovieToDashboardFn = (movie) => {
  localForage.getItem<string[]>('my array').then((value) => {
    const x = value;
    console.log(x)
  });
}
```

(Credit to @Elias Schablowski for suggesting this in the comments)

Comment: Or `localForage.getItem<string[]>('my array')`

Comment: I tried setting the type in the callback, `.then((value: string[])` but that still returned an error: `Argument of type '(value: string[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown) => void | PromiseLike<void>'.`. But casting the type (if i'm correct in calling it that ) does work! @EliasSchablowski if you want to create the answer I'll be happy to select it. Thanks both.

Comment: It's not exactly casting the parameter - it's more like you're specifying the function's signature by passing a type parameter.